# HTML-шаблоны игнорируют подключение таблицы стилей

Tags: html, css, django

Изучаю Django. Есть базовый шаблон basic.html в папке templates/bboard/layout:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "bboard/style.css" %}'>
        <title>{% block title %}Главная{% endblock %} - Доска Объявлений</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Объявления</h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
            <a href='{% url "index" %}'>Главная</a>
            <a href='{% url "add" %}'>Добавить</a>
            {% for rubric in rubrics %}
            <a href='{% url "by_rubric" rubric.pk %}'>{{rubric.name}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </nav>
        <section>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

От него идет три производных шаблона в папке templates\bboard: 1)index.html

```
{% extends 'bboard/layout/basic.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div class='b'>
    <h1>{{bb.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{bb.content}}</p>
    <p><a href='{% url "by_rubric" bb.rubric.pk %}'>{{bb.rubric.name}}</a></p>
    <p>{{bb.published|date:'Y.m.d H:i:s'}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

2)by_rubric.html

```
{% extends 'bboard/layout/basic.html' %}

{% block title %}{{current_rubric.name}}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Объявления</h1>
    <h2>Рубрика: {{current_rubric.name}}</h2>
    {% for bb in bbs %}
    <div>
        <h2>{{bb.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{bb.content}}</p>
        <p><a href='{% url "by_rubric" bb.rubric.pk %}'>{{bb.rubric.name}}</a></p>
        <p>{{bb.published|date:'d.m.Y H:i:s'}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

3)create.html

```
{% extends 'bboard/layout/basic.html' %}

{% block title %}Добавление объявления{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Добавление объявления</h1>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type='submit' value='Добавить'>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

В базовом шаблоне есть тег с подключением таблицы стилей: `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static "bboard/style.css" %}'>` . Проблема в том, что это никак не влияет на вид веб-страницы, будто я и не подключал таблицу стилей, шаблон просто его игнорирует.Более того, я даже специально писал тег link с ошибками, но это никак не влияло на результат, будто его просто нет.
Так же я писал шаблон index.html с нуля, без наследования, и вставлял туда тег link, но результата также не было.
Вот код style.css:

```
header h1 {
    font-size: 40pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background: url("bg.jpg") left/auto 100% no-repeat;
}

nav {
    font-size: 16pt;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

section {
    margin-left: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Загрузите `{% load static %}` в шаблоны, которые наследуются от `base.html`

Comment: @Sherlock не помогло, все так же

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена: по умолчанию при использовании тега static django ищет статические файлы (в том числе таблицы стилей) в папке static пакета приложения. У меня в теге static указан путь `'bboard/style.css'`, то есть django искал файл static/bboard/style.css, однако у меня в папке static не было вложенной папки bboard, а style.css хранился прямо там, в static.Получается, что django искал файл в папке, которой не существовало, поэтому таблица стилей и не подключалась.Как только я в папке static создал вложенную папку bboard и поместил style.css и bg.jpg в неё - всё заработало.